# 400 Bad Request in SpringCloudGateway?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

When i send a GET HTTP message to the SpringCloudGateway, it responses with 400: Bad Request!
How to solve this problem without modifying the request path.

The exception in Console

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 50: http://localhost:8080/api/user/application?data_a=%u589E
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(URI.java:2978) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(URI.java:3001) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3019) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.resolvePath(HttpOperations.java:360) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.<init>(HttpServerOperations.java:153) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.<init>(HttpServerOperations.java:137) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:200) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.4.jar:1.0.4]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) [netty-codec-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) [netty-codec-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) [netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:4.1.59.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

POM.xml

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This exception occurs only when the log level is debug.When it's info, the console is empty